# How to do the pandas.rolling with "stride" in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the rolling window function with "stride".
That means, the step is still 1.
But we can resample the index with a certain interval not only 1.
Do you have any idea of this? Thanks a lot.

For example:

```
df:  
  row0: 0  
  row1: 1  
  row2: 2  
  row3: 3  
  row4: 4  
  row5: 5  
  row6: 6   
  row7: 7  
  row8: 8  
  row9: 9   
  ...  

df1 = df.rolling(window=3, stride=3).sum() (where stride is not exist in pd.rolling)  
df1:   
  row0: nan  
  row1: nan  
  row2: nan  
  row3: nan  
  row4: nan   
  row5: nan  
  row6: 9 (row6+row3+row0)  
  row7: 12 (row7+row4+row1)    
  row8: 15 (row8+row5+row2)    
  row9: 18 (row9+row6+row3)     
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wouldn't really use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) in this case, but rather a [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
out = df.shift(2).add(df)
```

output:

```
      col
row0  NaN
row1  NaN
row2  2.0
row3  4.0
```

Comment: It's only fit for window=2, but in my situation the window is not only 2.
But still thanks

Comment: Can you provide another, more complex,example?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself.
The solution is:

```
def mean_with_stide(arr, stride):  
    return arr.iloc[::stride].mean()  

df.rolling(window=(win_len-1)*stide+1).apply(lambda x: mean_with_stride(x, stride))
```